# Timescaledb: How to stop all continuous aggregation jobs in a database

Tags: timescaledb

I am creating test and static analysis copies from TimescaleDB by dumping and reimporting the data. These databases are read-only and do not have new data coming in. However, as they are copies of the original TimescaleDB database, they still have their continuous aggregation jobs running.

These jobs, as they have nothing to do, still seem to cause unnecessary wake ups and background CPU usage.

How can I disable all continuous aggregation jobs in a TimescaleDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jobs are managed through automation policies. You should be able to identify the jobs that are scheduled with this

`SELECT * FROM timescaledb_information.jobs;`

You can either alter the job using the job id (example uses id 1000):

`SELECT alter_job(1000, scheduled => false);`

... or alter all the continuous aggregate jobs...

```
SELECT alter_job(job_id, scheduled => false)
FROM timescaledb_information.jobs
WHERE proc_name = 'policy_refresh_continuous_aggregate' 
AND hypertable_name = 'yourhypertablename'
```

ALTERNATIVELY if you want to completely delete them then you can use

`SELECT delete_job(1000);`

NOTE: this would stop any currently running job too. In case you want to restart them then alter might be better than delete.

You can get this from the TimescaleDB documentation by looking for automation policy, and it would be good to read through that so that you understand any impact this may have.

*Transparency: I work for Timescale*

Comment: Hi. I posted an update, as I could not apply your instructions 1:1, but eventually figured it out.

Comment: Thank you so much for updating on my suggestion... My tech is a bit rusty (I'm Community Manager) so this was super helpful!

Comment: Added a this information bit as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70104810/315168

Answer (score 1):

This is an update for greenweed's answer.

Selecting jobs by `hypertable_name` did not seem to work in my case. For some reason, my hypertables do not have sensible names and look generated:

```sql
# SELECT job_id, application_name, hypertable_name FROM timescaledb_information.jobs WHERE proc_name = 'policy_refresh_continuous_aggregate';
```

```
 job_id |              application_name              |       hypertable_name       
--------+--------------------------------------------+-----------------------------
   1000 | Refresh Continuous Aggregate Policy [1000] | _materialized_hypertable_3
   1001 | Refresh Continuous Aggregate Policy [1001] | _materialized_hypertable_4
   1002 | Refresh Continuous Aggregate Policy [1002] | _materialized_hypertable_5
   1003 | Refresh Continuous Aggregate Policy [1003] | _materialized_hypertable_6
   1004 | Refresh Continuous Aggregate Policy [1004] | _materialized_hypertable_7
   1005 | Refresh Continuous Aggregate Policy [1005] | _materialized_hypertable_8
   1006 | Refresh Continuous Aggregate Policy [1006] | _materialized_hypertable_9
```

I do not know how to map this `_materialized_hypertable` to the name I pass to `create_hypertable`.

```sql
SELECT FROM create_hypertable('candle_ohlcvx', ...)
```

Thus, I simply stop all jobs regardless of what table they belong to:

```sql
SELECT alter_job(job_id, scheduled => false) FROM timescaledb_information.jobs WHERE proc_name = 'policy_refresh_continuous_aggregate';
```

I confirm the jobs are now actually jobbed by observing there is no longer per minute output by TimescaleDb docker container in `docker logs`.

(Some ongoing jobs may still output, but seems to stop after a while.)

I also confirm this with

```sql
SELECT job_id, scheduled  FROM timescaledb_information.jobs WHERE proc_name = 'policy_refresh_continuous_aggregate';
```