# Cannot clone TimescaleDB using CREATE DATABASE ... TEMPLATE syntax

Tags: timescaledb

When trying to clone a TimescaleDB using PostgreSQL `CREATE TEMPLATE` feature I get an error:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE my_new_clone ENCODING 'utf8' TEMPLATE my_clone_source
```

Error:

> source database "my_clone_source" is being accessed by other users
> DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database.

There are no PSQL clients connected to the database.

What is causing this and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

TimescaleDB background workers for continuous aggregate jobs count as sessions.

To use a TimescaleDB database, with continuous integration jobs, as a template, you need to stop the continuous aggregate jobs first (You may also need to restart the database to really terminate the sessions of continuous aggregates, but I am unsure about this.)

You can stop all the continuous aggregate refresh jobs in your database with the following:

```sql
SELECT alter_job(job_id, scheduled => false) FROM timescaledb_information.jobs WHERE proc_name = 'policy_refresh_continuous_aggregate';
```

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69514708/timescaledb-how-to-stop-all-continuous-aggregation-jobs-in-a-database/69526244#69526244).